# python Magic 8 ball using functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make Magic 8-ball using python Functions. How to print all three functions in one line ? 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please write down the related script part that you have problems. Taking a screen shot of the code and sharing it is not the right way to ask a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the last line of answers:

```
" the Magic 8-Ball says:" + answers
```

You forgot to put parentheses after answers. Without them, it is trying to add the string to the answers function. With parentheses it will call answers() and append the return value.

P.S. you might want a space after the colon after "says".